# can someone explain what this regex does?

Tags: php, regex

I'm confused as to what this regex does:

```
preg_replace('/^\s*\((.+)\)\s*$/', '$1', $part);
```

Can someone give me a gist of what it does?

Comment: Replaces `[spaces here](a)[spaces here]` with `a`?

Comment: There are any number of online tools to explain it. http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html

Comment: How the heck is a regex "too localized"?

Comment: @Ignacio: I'll answer that if you tell me what *this* regex does: `preg_replace('/^\s*\((.?)\)\s*$/', '$1', $part);`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it will only help people with this exact regexp.

Comment: @Dani: And answers to any specific question will only help people with that question.

Comment: If that's really true for a given question, Ignacio, that question should be closed as well.

Comment: @Michael: But then that would mean that *all* questions on this site should be closed.

Comment: No, of course not, @Ignacio. If it could be useful to someone in the future, it stays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It finds lines that have a set of parens with whitespace optionally before and after, and removes the parens and whitespace. E.g.,

```
     (foo)
```

becomes

```
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

It matches...

- Optional leading whitespace.
- Literal `(`.
- Any characters except newline.
- Literal `)`.
- Optional trailing whitespace.

So it would match something like...

```
    (Hello)
```

...and replace it with...

```
Hello
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VzDi1j).

It is worth noting in a string such as...

```
(Hello)(World)
```

...it will return...

```
Hello)(World
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4rRUp9).

You could stop this matching by making the capturing group ungreedy by adding a `?` after the `+`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Oh whoops, forgot about those anchors.

Answer (score 0):

The function trims whitespace and parentheses. It replaces a string with any number of space characters at the beginning and end, plus opening and closing parentheses on either side, with group #1 (`$1`), which is the string without whitespace or parentheses at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up:

1. `\s*` matches any number of consecutive space-characters.
2. `\(` matches an opening parenthesis.
3. `(.+)` matches any consecutive characters.
4. `\)` matches a closing parenthesis.
5. `\s*` matches more whitespace.

Basically, it converts this:

```
        (Hello)
```

To this:

```
Hello
```